# Calling API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What is the correct way to call this api? The url of the api is: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/ ?

I want to read the "high" value...

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.high;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

What am i missing? Thx!!

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: The code you posted works for me. Are you seeking an optimised solution?

Comment: any errors on console ?

Comment: Most browsers are not going to like this, `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`.

Comment: Im ussing the W3school code viewer (https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_ajax) and when i run the code there is no high vallue shown, its keeps white like nothing to show

Comment: Mmm, created an html file in my computer and it doesnt work...

Comment: The w3schools example one will work, because it's the same Origin..  Unless your hosting your website at bitstamp.net, your not the same origin.

Comment: i changed the code to match the one i posted here. but it isnt giving me the high value that displays the api

Comment: I'm not sure how many time's I need to say this,  so I'll do it in big letters.. `IT'S NOT THE SAME ORIGIN`, browsers will not like you doing a XMLHttpRequest to a different domain, than the one your running from.   Your best option is to do this Server side.  Or if bitstamp have a JSONP option you could use that.

Comment: Keith it seems your right i will try to do it from a server side. thanks

Comment: @TomasBond  Isma, has found that if you pass a query parameter to bitstamp, they seem to enable COR's, not really sure why.. Maybe it's to force you to use cache-busting or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a timestamp to the URL made it work for me:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.high;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/?u" + new Date().getTime(), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

```js
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.high;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/?u" + + new Date().getTime(), true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Not sure what browser your using, but be aware your open to a `cross site scripting XSS attack`,..

Comment: Yeah, this change made the work. Mind explaining why this works?

Comment: Yes, it's not a caching issue.. It's bitstamp enables CORS when you using a query parameter..   Very strange, why it's not enabled without..

Comment: @Tomas Bond, I found this issue many times when making Ajax calls using XMLHttpRequest directly (without a framework like JQuery) I always thought it was a cache problem, i.e. the browser not making a real call to the service because the URL was already cached. Adding the time as a parameter will always generate a different URL thus avoiding the cache problem but Keith also has a point about CORS, not sure why it is enabled when a parameter is added to the request.